Creating indicator columns
I have this dataframe:



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D




1
value 1
value 2
value 3


2
value 4
value 5
value 6


3
value 7
value 8
value 9



I want to create an indicator column and a value column which will make the df look like this:



Column A
Indicator
Value




1
descriptionB
value 1


1
descriptionC
value 2


1
descriptionD
value 3


2
descriptionB
value 4


2
descriptionC
value 5


2
descriptionD
value 6


3
descirptionB
value 7


3
descriptionC
value 8


3
descriptionD
value 9



How do I make it happen?
Thank you.
I tried some for loops but so far no luck

chk following post: how-do-i-melt-a-pandas-dataframe

You can use melt to do this:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Column A': [1, 2, 3],
    'Column B': ['value 1', 'value 4', 'value 7'],
    'Column C': ['value 2', 'value 5', 'value 8'],
    'Column D': ['value 3', 'value 6', 'value 9']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

melted_df = df.melt(id_vars=['Column A'], var_name='Indicator', value_name='Value')

melted_df['Indicator'] = melted_df['Indicator'].replace({
    'Column B': 'descriptionB',
    'Column C': 'descriptionC',
    'Column D': 'descriptionD'
})


print(melted_df)

which gives you
   Column A     Indicator    Value
0         1  descriptionB  value 1
1         2  descriptionB  value 4
2         3  descriptionB  value 7
3         1  descriptionC  value 2
4         2  descriptionC  value 5
5         3  descriptionC  value 8
6         1  descriptionD  value 3
7         2  descriptionD  value 6
8         3  descriptionD  value 9

